# Xamarin: Translate EventListener From Java Into C# for Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am trying to find a way how to convert following pieces of code into c# xamarin, coming from java:

```
mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

                Log.i("Completion Listener","Song Complete");
                Toast.makeText(context, "Media Completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

This is a simple EventHandler which exists in either java and also .net for android. Unfortunately, I have not yet been able to find any way how to translate this correctly. Can you show me with this exact example?
Thank you:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The recommended way to do that is to use events, like in the code below.

```
mediaPlayer.Completion += MediaPlayer_Completion;
...
}
private void MediaPlayer_Completion(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Android.Util.Log.Info("Completion Listener", "Song Complete");
  Toast.MakeText(context, "Media Completed", ToastLength.Short).Show();
}
```

In case you are still missing java in C# and afraid of events you can do the following:

C# does not support anonymous interfaces. You need to create separate class which implements IOnCompletionListener.
for example it could be ActivityClass:

```
public class MyActivity: Activity, IOnCompletionListener
{
       public void OnCompletion(Android.Media.MediaPlayer mp)
        {
            Android.Util.Log.Info("Completion Listener", "Song Complete");
         Toast.MakeText(this, "Media Completed", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
...
   {
   ...
    mediaPlayer.SetOnCompletionListener(this);
   ...
   }
}
```

Or some other class which inherits from Java.Lang.Object and implements IOnCompletionListener.

if you are in Activity replace 'context' with 'this'

Comment: Thanks, but I am trying not to go with delegate here. Also, the mediaplayer.Completition doesnt fire when a song has finished playing so I am trying to avoid that.

Comment: splendid. this answers all my questions. thank you so much

Comment: @AccessDenied Can you please help me on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62365511/how-to-adapt-java-eventlisteners-to-c%e2%a7%a3 ?

Answer (score 0):

It can be as simple as adding this:

```
player.Completion += () => 
{   
    //Do what you want here. 
    playlistSongCounter++;
    player.Play();  
};
```